# Error when validating vfs

Tags: java, spring, jboss, cxf, javabeans

I currently have jboss 7 set up. trying to setup JAX-RS with CXF however I am getting this error:

```
13:43:29,166 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/C:/Users/mtatlong/Documents/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/java_cxf_rest_test.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@15 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
13:43:29,182 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."java_cxf_rest_test.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."java_cxf_rest_test.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "java_cxf_rest_test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

I have this beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <jaxrs:server id="bookservice" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="customerservice" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="demo.jaxrs.service.SecurityExceptionMapper" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="customerservice" class="demo.jaxrs.service.CustomerServiceImpl" />


</beans>
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but this seems to work:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
```

Was able to fix this by adding correct jars, apparently, jboss 7 has it's own off the shelf cxf jars, however the jars I was using with my application was a different version. I just matched the jars and it worked, also exclude jetty in classpath/pom.xml.